# Alter / Update PostgreSQL Sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence

How can I update the last_value field in my sequence and add 1 to it?

[image: table]

The query I tried: `ALTER SEQUENCE "seq_hours" SET 'last_value' = 'last_value' + 1`

However this did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setval()` with a subquery to get the value from a table, e.g.

```
SELECT setval('seq_hours', (SELECT max(last_value)+1 FROM t));
```

**EDIT**: This solution only makes sense if you want to set the current value of a sequence based on a value from a given table. If you only want the next possible value of a sequence you should use `nextval` as @a_horse_with_no_name suggested (see comments)

Comment: @yesIamFaded  or simply `select nextval('seq_hours')`